Why do most if not all monotheistic religions claim that God is omniscient, omnipotent, and omnibenevolent?
What is the psychological drive or set of psychological drives or set of emotions that compel monotheistic believers, especially in the Abrahamic religions, to espouse the 3 qualities of omniscience, omnipotence, and omnibenevolence?
There are 4 main psychological theories that attempt to explain the connection between the fear of death (death anxiety) and a person's degree of religiosity: buffering theory, terror-management theory, curvilinearity theory, and death apprehension theory. The Terror Management Theory, for example, hypothesizes that death anxiety is the reason why humans believe in gods and religions.
I'm looking for similar psychological or anthropological theories that explain why monotheistic religions embrace ideas such as omniscience, omnipotence, and omnibenevolence.
